# Mid animation, how do I reset my character to it's default pose, without having the history of the previous animation reversed

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes, pose-mode

I started an Animation, my character did a Flip 360, I did all the keyframes. Now my character is in a different place.

How do I reset my characters Rotation to its original pose?

But also that the Animation I did before goes directly, the shortest way, into the Default Pose when I'm doing a keyframe.

Because that is my Problem, when I do the keyframe from the model in default Pose via (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) my charcter Flips Back in Reverse 360 into the default pose and that's not what I want.